# Generating a uuid for a copied VMWare virtual machine

Tags: vmware, uuid

As per http://www.vmware.com/support/esx15/doc/esx15_runvm5.html, how would one go about generating the UUID format that is specified in the docs?

I'd like this to be a command line utility so I can re-use this in an automation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command:

```
  uuidgen | perl -ne '{ s/-//g; s/(.{2})/\1 /g; substr($_,23,1,"-"); print ; }'
```

Outputs:

```
CB 7B E9 47 F7 55 42 42-AC 16 46 C1 E9 08 35 53
```